# SQL Query select from multiple large tables, Execution Time too long

Tags: sql-server, performance

I have written a SQL Query that does what I need (I think) however it takes way too long to execute, as the query is searching through every record and Column and there are A LOT

I have tried using joins however my understanding of joins is limited and I did not manage

I tried to add a nested select statement in the where clause however didnt seem to help or Ive done it incorrectly

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
OCRD.[E_Mail] , 
OCPR.[E_MailL],
OCPR.[Name], 
OWHS.[WhsCode]

FROM  OCRD, OCPR, OWHS
WHERE OWHS.WhsCode = 'zzdb';
```

If Possible, I would like to check that the values in OCRD.[E_Mail] as well as OCPR.[E_MailL]are not duplicated but included from both tables.

I want the query to simply return Names and Emails, where WhsCode = 'zzdb'
and not take an hour+ to execute

Thank you. Any help appreciated

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: You are currently doing a cross join between the three tables, probably not what you want here.  Please add table structure to your question for all three tables.

Comment: Sorry to pile on, but this explains why Gordon and Tim have stated the above: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: Thanks for your help all, Im going to give this a shot again using joins

Comment: @RaymondNijland I totally agree but the likelihood that it would stop working for any of the vendors is incredibly small. The amount of code it could potentially break is staggering. Would hate to be the vendor who decided to stop allowing obsolete syntax and a company closes their doors as a result.

Comment: *"I totally agree but the likelihood that it would stop working for any of the vendors is incredibly small. The amount of code it could potentially break is staggering."* @SeanLange very true some vendors products (MySQL for example) also rewrite JOIN syntax into those old comma join syntax in the optimizer

Comment: I also agree with Sean's sentiments here, @RaymondNijland . I admit, that I do actually use the "old" format when creating a tally table; as `FROM N N1, N N2, N N3, N N4...` is far quicker (and easier) to write than `FROM N N1 CROSS JOIN N N2 CROSS JOIN N N3...`

Comment: @Larnu seams i also have mistaken it with something else in the standard which was deprecated and or removed form the Standards as SQL 92 -> `<from clause> ::= FROM <table reference> [ { <comma> <table reference> }... ]` it's still there..  SQL 2003/2008 `<from clause> ::= FROM <table reference list>

<table reference list> ::=
    <table reference>  [ { <comma>  <table reference>  }... ]`  it's seams it's never deprecated and or removed..

Comment: Ive now done this 
SELECT 
DISTINCT 
pr.[Name], 
rd.E_Mail,  
ws.WhsName
  FROM dbo.OCRD AS rd
  JOIN dbo.OCPR AS pr
  ON rd.E_Mail = pr.E_MailL
  JOIN dbo.OWHS as ws
  on pr.E_MailL = rd.E_Mail

  WHERE ws.WhsCode = 'zzdb'
Seems to be working fine, Can anybody Tell me if this would be including emails from both OCRD as well as OCPR

Comment: Since you are joining on the email column, only those records that have a matching email name in that column will be displayed.